# Export Canvas as .gif image

Tags: html, canvas, png, export, gif

I've been pulling my hair out trying to export my html5 canvas a .gif image,i was able to succesfully save it as a .png file. i dnt know what am doing wrong here is my simple code

```
canvas.onclick = function () {
window.location = canvas.toDataURL('image/gif');
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf) will answer your question. In short, try console.log'ing your data, and, not all browsers will support writing to a gif.

Comment: Could you accept (and upvote) this answer? That would be awesome :)